# Make all traffic go through residential proxies using OpenVpn

Tags: proxy, openvpn

I’m trying to achieve the following and wanted to get your thoughts if this something achievable.

I have some residential proxies and I have a Windows server, I want all the traffic of my Windows server to go through these proxies including browsers and all applications.

This is not possible with Windows so I thought about setting an OpenVPN server which will be configured with these residential proxies. Then when I connect to that vpn server from my windows box, all traffic should go through residential proxies?

Is this something possible, do you have any other thoughts?

Thanks in advance